# Understanding the line from Gunga Din

Tags: poetry, lexicon

So, in Kipling's *Gunga Din*, there's a piece in the second stanza:

> The uniform ’e wore
> Was nothin’ much before,
> An’ rather less than ’arf o’ that be’ind,
> For a piece o’ twisty rag
> An’ a goatskin water-bag
> Was all the field-equipment ’e could find.

Can anyone help me understand line 3?

> An’ rather less than ’arf o’ that be’ind.

It might me something obvious to a native, but I don't get what ’arf is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An’ rather less than ’arf o’ that be’ind.

Is an abbreviated version of

> And rather less than half of that behind.

In other words, the uniform was thin at the front and even more scanty in the rear.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense. I didn't read "before" as referring to the front part.